# Terminate Blender with Exit Code "1" when run from command line

Tags: python, blender

I am working with an automated Blender python script and I would like to know how to terminate it with an Exit Code 1 when an Exception occurs.

The problem seems to be that the exit code from blender is always 0 even if the python script fails.

The following script definately produces a non-zero exit code, but blender sets exit code to 0

```
def main():
    raise Exception("Fail")
    sys.exit(1)
```

I also tried the *--python-exit-code* command line argument but to no effect:

```
C:\blender.exe --python-exit-code 2 --disable-abort-handler -P bake.py
```

this gives a slightly better result, because I get the following message:

```
Error: script failed, file: 'bake.py', exiting with code 2.
```

Unfortunately the exit code is still 0.

Can anyone enlighten me with some explanations or solutions on how I can exit the process with the correct exit code?

Thanks a lot for any hints!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`--python-exit-code` as stated in the documentation sets the exit code if the command line script called with `--python` raises an exception, not when it exits with a non-zero code.

> Set the exit-code in [0..255] to exit if a Python exception is raised (only for scripts executed from the command line), zero disables.

Thus the only solution is to do your checking, and raise an exception manually, then catch it and exit in the `except` block. (If you don't exit right away, the exit code reverts to 0.

This code worked for me when doing unit tests inside a blender addon.

```
import unittest
from tests.my_test import MyTest
import sys

def run():
    suite = unittest.defaultTestLoader.loadTestsFromTestCase(MyTest)
    success = unittest.TextTestRunner().run(suite).wasSuccessful()
    if not success:
        raise Exception('Tests Failed')

try:
    run()
except Exception:
    sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. i guess the problem really was that I didn't catch the exception properly - thanks!